# CustomTranslator Category not accepting in Document Translator App

Tags: document, microsoft-translator

I tried adding document translator with custom translator category . Below is the input I gave which is same as category in my CustomTranslator.ai

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGLbC.png)

Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your 'Category ID' from the Projects page in Custom Translator into the 'Category' field in Document Translator. We'll fix the field label and sorry for the confusion.